# JSON Parse error - iPad/iPhone Only

Tags: php, iphone, ajax, json, ipad

I am working within the codeigniter framework and on page load making the following ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/beta/images/loadImages',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {id: id},
        success: function(json, textStatus, xhr) {
            alert('success');       
        }
        }, error: function(json, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

**strong text**

```
public function loadImages()
    {
        $galleryID = $this->input->post('id');

        $data      = array('images' => $this->image_gallery->get_slideImages($galleryID) );

        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

**Finally the model**

```
public function get_slideImages($galleryID)
    {
        $this->db->select('id');
        $this->db->where('galleryID', $id);

        $query = $this->db->get('image_images');

        $result = $query->result();
        return $result;
    }
```

**JSON Return in Chrome**

```
{"images":[{"id":"34","galleryID":"57","clientRef":"205","imageName":"769074051374530545.jpg","orgName":"P9180021.jpg","order":"0","timestamp":"1374530546"}]}
```

The error occurs only on the iPad and iPhone. SyntaxError: JSON Parse Error: Unrecognized token '<' Any ideas on this one?

Answer (score 1):

```
url: '/beta/images/loadImages',
type: 'POST'
```

If you are just loading something (especially on page load), why use `POST`? Use `GET` instead.

You are getting the JSON parse error because you aren't returning valid JSON (you are returning html/xml). The only possible explanation is you have some server side logic that dictates

```
if browser == mobile 
     return html/xml 
          else 
     return JSON
```